# All php sessions are getting destroyed

Tags: php, session

I have 2 different projects i use session in both;

In the 1st project

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['score'] = 0;
```

And in the other project:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = 1;
```

when I destroy session in anyone of them, it destroy session in both projects.

How do I only kill the session within one of the projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session_destroy( ); //destroys all sessions.
```

Try using

```
unset($_SESSION['score']);//or whatever selected session you want to delete
```

Answer (score 1):

store your session like that

```
$_SESSION["projet1"]["score"] = 0;

$_SESSION["Projet2"]["something"] = 1;
```

and to remove all session from a specific projet you can do

```
unset($_SESSION["projet1"]);
```